# .BAT file - What are all of the possible switches that will work outside a batch script?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

Is there a resource that lists all of the possible switches that you can use on a bat file?

I found this one that closes cmd.exe, which is very useful . . . "Startup.bat /B" . . . it took me hours to find it.

/B . . . Specifies to exit the current batch script instead of CMD.EXE. If executed from outside a batch script, it will quit CMD.EXE . . . http://www.computerhope.com/exithlp.htm . . . DOES LOWER CASE b WORK? YES

I put this bat file in my Startup folder, and use it as my Startup.  The bat file makes it very easy to disable *all* Startups, just by re-naming it with the .txt extension.

I wanted to see if there is a built-in switch like /S or /Q, where it would run the bat file silently, and you wouldn't see it . . . But maybe there isn't, on purpose, because it would be used for viruses.

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting#Switches

Comment: http://ss64.com/nt/ perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Batch files themselves do not have any inherent switches.

They *can* accept [parameters that can be passed into the batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551/how-to-pass-command-line-parameters-to-a-batch-file) to be used as switches (or other things) as needed by the commands within the batch, but those are defined/implimented by the author of the batch script.

The switch you're speaking of (`/B`) is for the `Exit` command.  If you want a list of switches for Exit (or practically any command prompt command), open a command prompt and type `exit /?`.

Comment: Links & replies help a lot TY!  Question solved. I was trying to answer this question:

"Scheduled task won't run .bat file" . . . My posts are on this page - first post is as . . . mb1280, Wednesday, August 03, 2016 9:04 PM . . . https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d47d116e-10b9-44f0-9a30-7406c86c2fbe/scheduled-task-wont-run-bat-file?forum=winservermanager&ppud=4

I thought that I needed the /B switch in "Startup.bat /B" . . . in order to close the DOS window . . . I see that I don't!

I've put the full story in the "Scheduled task won't run .bat file" page.